# My sql query with MAX, MIN and third field for HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the minimum and maximum price on a mysql(MyISAM) query.
I'm using this query for:

```
SELECT MAX(price_feed) as max, 
       MIN(price_feed) as min, 
       SQRT( POW(69.1 * (latitude_feed - 51.542980), 2) + POW(69.1 * (-0.149323 - longitude_feed ) * COS(latitude_feed / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
  FROM feed
 WHERE listing_type_feed = 'rental' 
       and property_type_feed IN ("Flat", "Apartament", "Penthouse", "Studio")
HAVING distance < 2
```

but it returns nothing, while when i try

```
SELECT price_feed as max, 
       price_feed as min, 
       SQRT( POW(69.1 * (latitude_feed - 51.542980), 2) + POW(69.1 * (-0.149323 - longitude_feed ) * COS(latitude_feed / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
  FROM feed 
 WHERE listing_type_feed = 'rental' 
       and property_type_feed IN ("Flat", "Apartament", "Penthouse", "Studio") 
HAVING distance < 2
```

It returns 2600 rows.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give some context on what you want? Looks like Min and Max(price) in an area? What rdbms are you using?

Comment: mysql with MyISAM. I want the min and max price in the area defined by the distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested query or CTE depending on your RDBMS

First you calculate what property are in a 2km radius and then you calculate the max/min prices from that result, also you dont need `having` instead you use the `where`clausule

```
SELECT MAX(price_feed) as max, MIN(price_feed) as min
FROM (
      SELECT price_feed
      FROM feed 
      WHERE 
           listing_type_feed = 'rental' 
      and property_type_feed IN ("Flat", "Apartament", "Penthouse", "Studio")      
      and SQRT( POW(69.1 * (latitude_feed - 51.542980), 2) + POW(69.1 * (-0.149323 - longitude_feed ) * COS(latitude_feed / 57.3), 2)) < 2
) as filter_properties
```

Comment: you just forgot the "as tablename" in the end. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In pure SQL it is a mistake to select fields that are not aggregate functions nor group by fields, in a query that uses aggregates or group by.

In mysql you can select any field, but if it is not a group by field or an aggregate function the value returned may be any value from the resultset. So it is undefined unless you group by a key.

In your first query there is no group by clause, so the aggregates use all rows as one group. And the value of distance is the value of a row (any).